# Only the creator should edit or remove a object, how?

Tags: python, django, django-permissions

I'm on a django app about academies, teachers and students.
I want to set some permissions, and the first one is that only the user who create a object (academy, teacher or student) could edit or remove it.

There's a object property that knows the user who create it?
Or I should create a foreign key to it?

My idea is to read this property and check it when building the HTML to show or not the edit and remove button, is this okay?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a ForeignKey to auth.User. What is the question?

Comment: Once you have a ForeignKey to user, verify the right user is connected in the view. Note that you'll need mode work with the admin part if you want to modify rights of administrators